# TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone in an ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, timezone

How does TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone work if run in an ASP.NET app? Does it return the timezone of the application pool running the application? If using impersonation, does it return the timezone of the user its impersonating?

Comment: Keep in im mind too that this will have nothing to do with the timezoone of the client accessing your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the time zone on the computer where the code is executing. This is stored in HKLM i.e. it is a machine level setting not a user level. So it doesn't matter if impersonaltion is used. The value would still be the same. Check [TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx) which is [TimeZoneInfo.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. It may belong in a different question, but if this is a system-level value, why does it change when I change my timezone using the taskbar? Is it because I am an admin on the machine?

Comment: Admins obviously can change the timezone. For non-admin users, I believe this permission can be controlled by group policy.